# Как сделать такое всплывающее окно

Tags: java, android, dialogfragment

Нужно создать всплывающее окно как на картинке ниже, при клике на плюсик всплывает обычное диалоговое окно с edit text'ом, куда пользователь вводит строку, после чего эта строка отображается как элемент в list'е с картинки. Когда пользователь введет все что нужно, он нажимает на кнопку сохранить (на картинке ее нет), далее все данные преобразуются в обычный java класс и уходят в другой лист под этим диалоговым окном. Конечно, можно все это сделать и в отдельном activity, но тогда на экране будет слишком много свободного места. А чтоб сделать это все в фрагменте нужно выделять контейнер, места для которого нет, ведь весь экран занят листом.
[image: так должно выглядеть окно]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Тебе подойдет DialogFragment, это по сути fragment который отображается в виде диалогового окна.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment

Answer (score 2):

Делаешь еще одну активити. 
Создаешь стиль для нее, что то типа этого

```
 <style name="Dialog.AddBitmap" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.FixedSize">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowFixedWidthMajor">@dimen/width_window_major_add_bitmap</item>
    <item name="windowFixedWidthMinor">@dimen/width_window_minor_add_bitmap</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMajor">@dimen/height_window_major_add_bitmap</item>
    <item name="windowFixedHeightMinor">@dimen/height_window_minor_add_bitmap</item>
</style>
```

Тут как видно стиль активити типа диалог, то есть экран не полностью занимающий дисплей. Где dimen - это размер, создается  в values|dimens

```
 <dimen name="width_window_major_add_bitmap">90%</dimen>
<dimen name="width_window_minor_add_bitmap">90%</dimen>
<dimen name="height_window_major_add_bitmap">75%</dimen>
<dimen name="height_window_minor_add_bitmap">75%</dimen>
```

Как понятно - процент от параметров экрана. В маснифесте, в поле этой активити обязательно указываем этот стиль

```
android:theme="@style/Dialog.AddBitmap"
```

Вызываем ее методом "startActivityForResult()" и получаем ответ.